# unable to detect UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hey guys I am unable to find or connect my `UITextField loginId` with my custom `viewcontroller.h` file.  when I try to get that class using `NSString *data = loginId.text;`it tells me that it is non existant.

`.h` file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

UITextField *loginId;
UITextField *password;

@interface loginController : UIViewController
- (IBAction) loginBegin:(id) sender;

@end
```

`.m` file:

```
   NSString *intakePass = loginId.text;
```

I tried cleaning my project but that seems not to work.  I notice that when I go to the storyboard to add in a custom class usually the classname I make in the `.h` file will drop down but nothing comes up.  But it is set to `loginId`.

Suggestions, thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**IBOutlet** is the Key to **Make them visible in XIB**. So u must specify them as IBOutlet.

You must drag UITextField from library, not other components.Please verify it on XIB that you are connecting Text Field and make sure the **class name of text field**. it **should be UITextField or UITextField Subclass**.

```
 @interface loginController : UIViewController{

     IBOutlet UITextField *loginId;
     IBOutlet UITextField *password;

  }
  @property(weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *loginId;

  @property(weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *password;

  - (IBAction) loginBegin:(id) sender;

  @end
```

[Apple Documentation says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitConstantsReference/Reference/reference.html)

[image]

Comment: Okay but I am still having trouble connecting it

Comment: You must drag UITextField not other components.Please verify it on XIB that you are connecting Text Field. and make sure the class name of text field. it should be UITextField or UITextField Subclass

Comment: I have ARC turned off so if I use the weak,nonatomic setters i get an error, is that okay if I don't use them?

Comment: replace weak to assign

Answer (score 0):

IBOutlet your UITextField as below in your .m file:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property(weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *loginId;

@property(weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *password;

@end
```

now you can connect your textfile in xib